# Adding additional menu item on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have 4 links. 3 of them should be visible but whenever one of the 3 have been clicked the 4th should appear. if any of the first 3 gets pressed nothing should change but if the 4th one (the one who appeared on first click) is clicked it should disappear and there again should be only 3. Any ideas on how to do it? Probably it's going to be done using JQuery?!

Comment: Did you try anything? I would say yes, I have some ideas. Yes probably with jQuery. or 42 maybe. By the way, I would like to get rich, anybody can help me? I think it should involve work, what do you think? Is working hard good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MPmE8/)

For a set of links:

```
<div>
    <a href='#' id='link1' onclick='toggle(this)'>link 1</a>
    <a href='#' id='link2' onclick='toggle(this)'>link 2</a>
    <a href='#' id='link3' onclick='toggle(this)'>link 3</a>
    <a href='#' id='link4' style='display:none' onclick='toggle(this)'>link 4</a>
</div>
```

And with javascript:

```
var disp = false;

function toggle(el) {
    if (disp) {
        if (el.id == 'link4') {
            document.getElementById('link4').style.display='none';
            disp = false;
        }
    } else {
        if ((el.id == 'link1') || (el.id == 'link2') || (el.id == 'link3')) {
            document.getElementById('link4').style.display='block';
            disp = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When you click any of the first 3 links, the 4th will appear, and when you click the 4th it (the 4th link) will disappear.

**Edit:** As per requested, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MPmE8/1/) is a demo of the same thing with fading.  As for the code, the HTML is the same and the JQuery code is:

```
var disp = false;

function toggle(el) {
    if (disp) {
        if (el.id == 'link4') {
            $('#link4').fadeOut();
            disp = false;
        }
    } else {
        if ((el.id == 'link1') || (el.id == 'link2') || (el.id == 'link3')) {
            $('#link4').fadeIn();
            disp = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any ideas what to add so it fadesin instead of just appear?

Comment: @kokozz, yes, it requires you to use JQuery instead of pure JavaScript, I'll make a new demo and add the new code in an edit.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! It's flickering a bit but on jsfiddle its right, so I'm guessing theres something in my code that is making that issue. Again- thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the 3rd and 4th links an id and set the style `visibility: hidden;`

Then using JQuery:

```
var 3rdLink = $("#3rdLinkId"),
    4thLink = $("#4thLinkId"); //just good practice    
3rdLink.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  //just in case it's a hyperlink
    4thLink.css('visibility', 'visible');
)};
```

You have plenty of options to show an element using JQuery and it's all pretty easy.

**But Really, this is all over the place. A simple Google search would have sufficed**

Comment: Not sure if this is the intended behavior, but visibility does not remove the element from the page it only hides it (i.e. it will still affect other page elements because it still takes up the same space it would occupy if it was visible). - Not saying the answer isn't right, I just wanted to clarify the behavior.

Comment: Correct. Adjusting the visibility property is the most basic way to make an element _appear_ on an event. Considering the very vague specs of the question, I thought it was an appropriate option to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If your links looks something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="show" onclick="show4()" >link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="show" onclick="show4()" >link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="show" onclick="show4()" >link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4" class="hide" onclick="hide4()" >link 4</a>
```

You could use this:

```
<style>
.hide {display: none;}
.show {display: block;}
</style>
<script>
function show4() 
{
    document.getElementById('link4').style.display = "block";
}
function hide4() 
{
        document.getElementById('link4').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could also write the javascript to just change the classname like this `document.getElementById('link4').className = "[hide|show]";`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your html looks like this

```
<div id="link-container">
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
</div>
```

Css

```
#link-container a:last-child{display:none}
```

Javascript using jQuery framework

```
$(function(){
    $('#link-container').on('click', 'a',function(e){
        var $t = $(this),
            $last = $t.siblings('a').addBack().last();
        if($last[0] != this){
           $last.toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/n2n92/)